# auto-enabling activeX communication on a particular website

Tags: javascript, .net-2.0, activex, bho

I have custom made BHO, and on first run, my website javascript communicates with BHO.

if it is able to communicate with BHO, we say IE add-on is installed, otherwise we push the installed file.

problem: When IE add-on is installed, IE7,8,9 ask "a website is trying to communicate with activeX control" .. is there a way to disable that notification, and auto enable the control for that particular website?

//mouse

Answer (score 0):

The activeX control must be singed using a code signing certificate obtained from CA like Verisign, Comodo, GoDaddy etc.

//mouse